# Lose databinding possibilities with UoW pattern in Linq to Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext, unit-of-work

I'm currently working on my first Linq-to-Sql app.
I've implemented the data-access methods with a short dataContext lifetime like this:

```
public IProduct GetByCode(string code)
{
   using (var db = new dataContext())
   {
      return db.Products.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Code == code);
   }
}
```

I'm wondering how to get change notifications of clr-properties. 
When you have a single dataContext this is not a problem.

So the question is: How do I get in-memory changes of an entity?!

I have an entity which can be modified in two different screens. Updates in one screen should be visible in the other. The only possibility I see is to let the dataContext have the same lifetime as both screens, wich comes down to application lifetime.

I feel friction between the Unit of Work pattern (per request) and full databinding capabilities. Please tell me what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL generated classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged so you can use that to monitor for changes to the original object in memory.

However, both of your screens would need to be pointing at the SAME instance, not having their own copies (which sounds like this is the case?).

You don't say what type of binding your UI screens use: if it's WPF/Silverlight and you are using binding, you may want to use a MVVM approach, where the data source is shared for the two screens.